# Error when passing a initialized vector as a reference

Tags: c++, stl

I've a function:

```
std::string GraphList::_dfs(int src, std::vector<int>& visited)
```

and I'm calling it like below :

```
std::vector<bool> visited(NUM_V, false);
return _dfs(src, visited);
```

I'm getting the below error :

```
a reference of type "std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool>>"
```

If I pass an uninitialized vector, it works fine, but why is the compiler complaining when I pass an initialized vector ?

Comment: `std::vector<int>` != `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: How silly of me, it was an oversight.  Working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `vector<bool>` as an argument to a function that expects a `vector<int>` for the corresponding parameter, which is of a different type with no implicit conversion possible between the two types, hence the error.

Comment: Wouldn't that need the parameter to take a `const&` though?

Comment: @Eljay, you are right. I've removed that particular paragraph.